# Debugging VI magic

Tags: macros, vim

For some reason, when I use single line search movements (f,F,t,T) in VI macros, and I try to execute them, they're noticeably slow (~5 seconds)

Other macros not using those movements are fine and normal.

Is there an easy way to find what is causing this?

Comment: When you say "macros" do you mean things recorded with q (and typically invoked with @) or do you mean mappings created with map, nmap, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you have other key maps starting with 'f', 'F', 't' and 'T', and Vi is waiting for a time-out before executing them. What does "`:verbose map f`", "`:verbose map F`", etc. show?

Comment: That was helpful! It pointed me to the plugin that was causing this, removing it solved the problem. Thanks!